# Two subsets with the same span?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose spans equal each other but their intersection is the empty set. I was thinking $v_1=\{(1,0,0)\}$ and $v_2=\{(0,1,0)\}$ but I'm not sure..would this work?

Comment: The reason your example won't work is because these vectors are orthogonal and hence have mutually orthogonal spans.

Comment: please consider selecting an answer as your favorite by ticking the check mark at the top left of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher's answer is really good but I enjoy giving off the wall answers:

Let the first set be the empty set and the second set be $\{0\}$, their intersection is the empty set and their span is the same because
[Span of an empty set is the zero vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185255/span-of-an-empty-set-is-the-zero-vector)

Comment: I feel that's a somewhat confusing definition, since the 0 vector can itself be considered a subspace.

Comment: Read the top voted answer on that page, I agree that this is an unusual answer but.... but applying the definitions I'm completely correct.

Comment: @Christopher, (0) is a vector subspace, while {0} is the vector which generates the former space.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You just need two non-zero vectors where one is a scalar multiple of the other. Can you see why?

In your attempt, $v_1$ and $v_2$ do not have the same span.

Answer (score 0):

Does it looks like the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is the same?. This certainly wouldn't work, $v_1$ generates the set of $\{(a,0,0):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $v_2$ generates $\{(0,b,0):b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ that only have in common the null vector.

I'll give you and intuitive hint: How many ways do you have to span a line or a plane?, how can you set the vectors to span them?. Consider for example a line that goes along the x-axis, would it make a difference if you define de subspace using a vector that points in to the negative direction instead of the positive?.

Comment: Kind of a side question: if two subsets of a linear space have the same span, does it mean they are always linear dependent?